# Merge and alternate 2 arrays into single array

Tags: javascript

I have beginner scripting skills and am using a form of JavaScript, ECMA-262 that is found in a program called Opus Pro (Digital Workshop, UK).

I've been searching online, without success, to find a way to merge and alternate number elements from 2 arrays into a third merged array. I've found a few scripts on this site, but they use functions like "push" which are not found in this script language, so can't be used.

My current script which creates one array for a set of randomly chosen numbers, (math.random),1-6, needs to be modified to create the 2 arrays (1-3 and 4-6), then alternately merge a value from the first array with a value from the second array, until the new array has 6 values taken from these (sub-) arrays:

current, unmodified script:

```
function separate()
{
  for(i=1;i<=listamount;i++)
     {
     //create 6 random numbers from 1-6
     temp = Math.round(Math.random()*(6))
     if (temp == 0){temp = 1}
     if (temp == 7){temp = 6}

        randomset[i] = temp
     }         
}
```

This needs to be revised so that the final randomlist array (call it newrandomlist[i]) would be an alternating mix like 2,6,1,4,3,5, but merged from 2 randomly ordered/created sub-arrays (1-3 and 4-6). Alternating values, from each randomly ordered/constructed sub-array, are critical to the functioning of the rest of the scripts in the project. I've tried any number of ideas, all unsuccessfully.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: ECMA-262 has push on arrays. `var a=[]; a.push(1);` works in ECMA-262 (3rd edition). Your problem might be elsewhere.

Comment: Does your scripting language also have a different `random` implementation? It should never return `7` here, and mapping `0` to `1` adds a bias.

Comment: ECMA-262 has the Array object which has the `.push()` method.  You can see it yourself in the [ECMA spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) in section 15.4.4.7.

Comment: I've just found and scanned through [the documentation](http://www.digitalworkshop.com/downloads/dl_manual.shtml) ([direct link to pdf](http://www.digitalworkshop.com/manuals/OpusScriptReference.pdf) ("Copyright 1997-2005"). The documentation has over 400 pages, and looks either inconsistent, or broken: Semicolons are rarely used. I've seen a case where `Function` is spelled with uppercase `F`. Oh, and some strings were created using `new String("Opus")`.

Answer (score 3):

ECMA-262 has the Array object which has the `.push()` method.  You can see it yourself in the [ECMA spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) in section 15.4.4.7.

To merge two arrays by alternating between random elements from each array, you can do this:

```
function mergeTwoRandom(arr1, arr2) {

    function extractRandom(arr) {
        var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
        var result = arr[index];
        // remove item from the array
        arr.splice(index, 1);
        return(result);
    }

    var result = [];
    while (arr1.length || arr2.length) {
        if (arr1.length) {
            result.push(extractRandom(arr1));
        }
        if (arr2.length){
            result.push(extractRandom(arr2));
        }
    }
    return(result);
}
```

If you want to do it without `.push()`, you can do it like this:

```
function mergeTwoRandom(arr1, arr2) {

    function extractRandom(arr) {
        var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
        var result = arr[index];
        // remove item from the array
        arr.splice(index, 1);
        return(result);
    }

    var result = [];
    while (arr1.length || arr2.length) {
        if (arr1.length) {
            result[result.length] = extractRandom(arr1);
        }
        if (arr2.length){
            result[result.length] = extractRandom(arr2);
        }
    }
    return(result);
}
```

If you also don't have `.splice()`, you can do it like this:

```
function mergeTwoRandom(arr1, arr2) {

    function removeItem(arr, index) {
        for (var i = index; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
            arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
        }
        arr.length = arr.length - 1;
    }

    function extractRandom(arr) {
        var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
        var result = arr[index];
        // remove item from the array
        removeItem(arr, index);
        return(result);
    }

    var result = [];
    while (arr1.length || arr2.length) {
        if (arr1.length) {
            result[result.length] = extractRandom(arr1);
        }
        if (arr2.length){
            result[result.length] = extractRandom(arr2);
        }
    }
    return(result);
}
```

Comment: Probably not a full implementation of ECMAScript, see my comment at the question. Broken software is broken.

Comment: I added a version that doesn't use `.push()`.

Comment: If `push` does not exist, do you think that `splice` is defined?

Comment: @RobW - I'm doing the best I can with the information I'm given.  The OP needs to chime in here.  Obviously a manual version of `.splice()` could be written if needed just like I used a manual version of `.push()`.  If the environment is that broken, then the first advice is to pick a better environment!

Comment: Added a third version that doesn't use `.splice()` either.

Comment: According to his profile page, it looks like he left after posting the question. Well-deserved upvote for your sincere efforts ;)

Comment: Hi,I'm new to this board so I hope I am placing my replies in the correct place. I checked and "splice is also not available. Here's the scripting manual's URL: http://www.digitalworkshop.com/manuals/OpusScriptReference.pdf. So, it may need to be manually written. Little choice about the authoring environment, since the project is done in it now. This is only difficulty. Would like to solve. Thanks everyone for the help. Any manual version of the splice be a help. Then I can try it in the program editor, see if it works.

Comment: OK, let me try the newest version, see if I can get it to work. I also have to re-write the random arrays first, (to get 3 random num's between 1-3 in first array and 3 random nums 4-6 in second array. Then I will have arr1, arr2 to try out. I'm a beginner at scripting (most actions, events in the program are pre-done, no scripting. I'll try. Much thanks. PS: I didn't know the replies would be so rapid, so I did leave. Thought it would take hours. :)

Comment: @user1134527 - I did not undertand the 1-3 and 4-6 part of your question (and still don't) which is why I didn't incorporate that.  this code does an alternating merge in random order from both source arrays.

Comment: Hi, The project is an eLearning lesson and one of the animation exercises is this game-like component: the script hides and shows (blinks) one of 3 shapes (lights) on one side and then alternately blinks one of 3 shapes on the other side. The shapes are chosen randomly. So needs 2 separate arrays of 3-each, randomly chosen. Currently (see script above), it is set up incorrectly: all 6 shapes randomly chosen and placed in one array, so shapes on the same side of the screen show/hide instead of across the screen, back and forth.

Comment: In any event, I tried the above scripts in the Opus editor and got multiple errors: [] is not recognized. Difficult to say why other errors since only a line is id'd in the error message. I'm going to have to try to solve this using the Opus Script. It appears that it doesn't support some of the ECMAScript functions/syntax. Thank you for your kind help.

Comment: @user1134527 - You can substitute `var result = new Array();` in place of `var result = [];`, but this is a really bad implementation of javascript if it doesn't support `[]`.

Comment: Thanks once again. Been trying for a few hours. No joy. Going to stop for now, see if I can figure out another way to accomplish the task.