# Complex Building/Sorting Arrays

Tags: javascript

I'm have beginner skills and am hoping someone can help me with a complex script in JavaScript ECMA-262 (as basic a JS script as possible, since the program I am using has only older implementation of ECMA-262. So some some array functions like "splice" even "concat" are not found in the language reference for this program. But basic JS works OK).

I am trying to create an array totaling 6 numbers from 2 separate subarrays (subarrayA=1,2,3 and subarrayB=4,5,6), alternately placing a number (chosen randomly from each subarray) from each subarray into the final 6 item array. Also, no duplicates.

So, for example, 3,6,1,4,2,5.

I've tried online searching, this board, trying out zipper methods from 2 subarrays, % to pick out odd/even, etc. So far, nothing has worked. But at least I've gotten some more knowledge allowing me to ask the question in a way that may help create a more specific solution. I would hard code this, but I think that the number of possible variations/cases may be quite large?

I am hoping someone can suggest a script/function in basic JS that can (1) set up each random subarray, then (2) create the final 6 item array.

Kind Regards,

Comment: At least mention *which* implementation you're using. In your previous question, I did some efforts, and [located the documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11658089/merge-and-alternate-2-arrays-into-single-array#comment15449504_11658089). But don't expect to get help without giving a good description of the problem ("Basic JS" is a vague description).

Comment: Hi Rob,Thank you for trying to help. I'm not sure how to describe the implementation. If you mean the Opus documentation. I'll add it here:http://www.digitalworkshop.com/manuals/OpusScriptReference.pdf.What I realized after trying the suggested scripts, is that the random that I had originally posted was incorrect. Plus, I needed to better understand what I am looking for in order to ask the correct question. I think this is an improved presentation of the issue for resolution. Much thanks.

Comment: Your two requirements seem a bit odd. If you're creating the two random 3 item arrays just to combine them into the 6 item array couldn't you just generate 6 random numbers, add 3 into each smaller array and add all 6 into a longer array? (I'm assuming this is all part of a longer project with other requirements, but just a thought).

Comment: Why do you think you can't use `splice` or `concat` - where the hell does it execute? You should really use polyfills for those.

Comment: The implementation is a flashing lights animation for an eLearning lesson. 3 lights on the left side (1,2,3) and 3 on the right side (4,5,6). Similar to a Simon type game animation, but changed in this exercise, the flashing lights need to go left to right, not up and down on the same side. So, they flash from one side to the other in the random pattern. Hope this helps to clarify.

Comment: @user1134527 I think that it's better to contact your teacher or the [company itself](http://www.digitalworkshop.com/support/index.shtml). I haven't seen anyone on this site with the specific expertise for your software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're restricted to a sub-set of the modern JS API, I would probably take the approach of first merging the two arrays (iteratively) then applying a random sort. Something like:

```
var arr1 = [1,2,3], arr2 = [4,5,6];
for (var i=0, len = arr2.length; i<len; i++) arr1[arr1.length] = arr2[i];
arr1.sort(function() { return 0.5 - Math.random(); });
```

`arr1` is now an array of the 6 numbers in random order, no repeats.

[EDIT] - based on the discussion below, try this.

```
//prep - two arrays, randomised order
var arr1 = [1,2,3].sort(r_sort),
    arr2 = [4,5,6].sort(r_sort),
    final_arr = [],
    smallest_array = arr1.length < arr2.length ? arr1 : arr2;
function r_sort() { return 0.5 - Math.random(); }

//build final array - intersecting the two arrays
for (var i=0, len = smallest_array.length; i<len; i++) {
    final_arr[final_arr.length] = smallest_array[i];
    if (smallest_array == arr1 && arr2[i])
        final_arr[final_arr.length] = arr2[i];
    else if (smallest_array == arr2 && arr1[i])
        final_arr[final_arr.length] = arr1[i];

}

//result
alert(final_arr);
```

Comment: Thank you for this script. Unfortunately, the program script (which is limited, see above and scripting reference) cannot use "push". Everything else, but not "push". The set 1,2,3 needs to be inter-leaved (alternate with) the set:4,5,6. I think that this array of 6 can have two members of arr1 following each other. It needs to be arr1,arr2,arr1,arr2,arr1,arr2.

Comment: @user1134527 - Edited to avoid push - how's that?

Comment: Push is not in this authoring program's (Opus) scripting reference guide. If I use "push" is displays an error in the script editor.So, I would need to use a script that does not include "push". The bigger problem is that the final array cannot contain 2 or 3 or more elements from the same subarray. For example, 1 cannot be followed by 2 or 3, it must be followed by an element from the second subarray (4 or 5 or 6). The final array controls which lights will flash (show/hide). Flashing lights must be one side to the opposite side, not on the same side.

Comment: I did edit the post to avoid push. Re: the other point, well this makes it a little less random and harder to do. Would a satisfactory outcome be `1,4,2,5,3,6`, but that every time?

Comment: Thank you, I see that push is gone. But the other point is critical. I understand that this could be less random. But it would be much better if it can be as random as possible. 1,4,2,5,3,6 every time would not work. I understand the challenges of randomizing, but somehow, if possible, it needs to be more random. Reason for random: more challenging, will hold the lesson taker's interest better. If same pattern every time, will not hold their attention/interest.

Comment: Sorry, that changes the game rather. Feel free to vote up the answer for at least getting you on the right lines! Joke... sort of. Good luck with the rest of it.

Comment: Thank you. Maybe, this cannot be done?I did try to vote, but my "reputation" needs to be higher to be permitted to vote.

Comment: So far, I've gotten the first script working, creating a random array of 6, as expected. Now, I will see if I can add the second script for sorting. Will report back. There is no"alert" in this program, but I think I can do debug.trace(final_arr). I'm getting an error which may be related to [], since this is not in the program's language.

Comment: By the way, for the first script, I had to use: var arr1 = new Array;
arr1[0] = 1;
arr1[1] = 2;
arr1[2] = 3;

var arr2 = new Array;
arr2[0] = 4;
arr2[1] = 5;
arr2[2] = 6;for (var i=0, len = arr2.length; i<len; i++) arr1[arr1.length] = arr2[i];
arr1.sort(function() { return 0.5 - Math.random(); });

Comment: This line gives me an error: smallest_array = arr1.length < arr2.length ? arr1 : arr2; but the program's script editor does not specify what that error is. Nothing I change, like adding () helps.

Comment: OK, it seems your implementation doesn't even support ternary conditions. These would need to be converted to traditional `if-else` conditions. The script I posted definitely works in normal implementations of JS.

Comment: I tried if-else, but no success: if (arr1.length > arr2.length)
    {
     smallest_array = arr1
    }
    else
    {
    smallest_array = arr2
    }

Comment: No more errors, but only array elements 2,3 make 2 lights go on:      arr1.sort(r_sort)
arr2.sort(r_sort)
var final_arr = new Array()
if (arr1.length > arr2.length)
    {
     smallest_array = arr1
    }
    else
    {
    smallest_array = arr2
    }
function r_sort() { return 0.5 - Math.random(); }

for (var i=0, len = smallest_array.length; i<len; i++) {
    final_arr[final_arr.length] = smallest_array[i];
    if (smallest_array == arr1 && arr2[i])
        final_arr[final_arr.length] = arr2[i];
    else if (smallest_array == arr2 && arr1[i])
        final_arr[final_arr.length] = arr1[i];
}

Comment: OK, had forgotten to use final_arr[i] in next script. So, this works. Only problem: it stops after 6 lights. The original script got the array using for(i=1;i<=listamount;i++), where listamount was the number of lights that the person was able to correctly click (like Simon Says game). If I use final_arr[i] then I get only 6 every time because this i value is 6 array elements. So, I have to figure out how to use the for(i=1;i<=listamount;i++) in the revised script. I'll keep trying. Any suggestions? Much thanks for this help.

Comment: Only problems: it stops after 5 lights. And, always the same lights.

Comment: The random array is used in the remaining script: if array element[0]=1, object1.hide(),object1.show() //creates appearance of light flashing on/off, etc for 6 objects (6 lights). Like Simon Says game, if person clicks on each light that has flashed, it adds another light to the sequence (++). Click incorrect:pattern and game stop. So far script is always 1,5,2,6,3 then repeats 1,5,2,6,3. So, not yet fully working. I tried a few changes, but it should go beyond 1,5,2,6,3 and it should be a new random array each time it is again played.